# Multi screen support not working

Tags: android, android-layout, multiscreen

I am writing this app to show month days as bubbles .but I can’t  figure out how to make it work with different screen sizes. I am testing it in galaxy S3. if is use: 
Layout-large or layout-sw320dp show small buttons
but Layout-sw360dp shows over scale button
does i need a different layout for each dives or what.

The original size for images used as background for the buttons is 64*64 
Here a part of the code

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
tools:context="calendar.test.MainCalendar" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/Day11"
    android:layout_width="59dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bluroff"
    android:text="@string/d1"
    android:onClick="startFunc" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Day12"
    android:layout_width="59dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blurnight"
    android:text="@string/d2"
    android:onClick="test" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Day13"
     android:layout_width="59dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blurmorning"
    android:text="@string/d3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Day14"
    android:layout_width="59dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blurevening"
    android:text="@string/d4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Day15"
     android:layout_width="59dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bluroff"
    android:text="@string/d5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Day16"
   android:layout_width="59dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bluroff"
    android:text="@string/d6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Day17"
    android:layout_width="59dp"
    android:layout_height="59dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bluroff"
    android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
    android:text="@string/d7" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it does not change the size of the buttons when screen size change should i make a layout for every dives or what?

Answer (score 0):

you can use sp instead of dp. And put your image and other drawable things like that folder:
you can use sp instead of dp and put that folder your image and other drawable things.like that

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml // layout for normal screen size ("default") 
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml // layout for large screen size
...

res/drawable-mdpi/graphic.png // bitmap for medium-density
res/drawable-hdpi/graphic.png         // bitmap for high-density
```

For more information:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: in the link they recommend using dp for multi screen and use sp for font

Comment: i try this nothing change